# Getting error when I run npm run server on Vue JS project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-pwa

I added PWA in this project using `vue add pwa` using Vue Cli.
It installs two packages 
"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
"register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",

But when I run `npm run serve / npm run build` it's showing bellow error.

```
INFO  Starting development server...
0% compiling ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some issue with `"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "v5"`
Downgrade `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` to `"v4.5.15"`

First Run `npm uninstall @vue/cli-plugin-pwa` in terminal
then
Run `npm i -D @vue/cli-plugin-pwa@4` this will install latest release of version 4

Comment: You saved me a lot of debugging time, thanks for that!